# Hybrid Authentication using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a **daemon app** which currently supports Basic Authentication for on-premise using Exchange Web Services and also supports Modern Authentication for Exchange Online using Microsoft Graph.

Now I have a requirement to support Hybrid Authentication in my application. I went through below documentation to find out more about Hybrid authentication:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-hybrid

Here are my questions:

1. Will Hybrid authentication be supported via Microsoft Graph?
2. How will I get the Rest end points which needs to be accessed to get access token and other user data like events in Hybrid authentication?
3. Will the access token and rest endpoints flow be same for Hybrid and Modern auth using Microsoft Graph?
4. A basic understanding of Hybrid flow from Api integration point of view.

Any information will be very helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @baywet  Please help on this?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's supported for limited feature set (Mail, Calendar, Contacts). Check the above documentation itself.

Comment: 2 & 3. When Microsoft Graph identifies that a REST API call is attempting to access an on-premises mailbox in a hybrid deployment, it proxies the REST request to an on-premises REST endpoint which then processes the request. This discovery makes accessing the REST API possible.

Comment: 4. Here's the [detailed workflow](https://lecafedeva.wordpress.com/2019/03/15/deep-dive-how-to-configure-exchange-on-premise-server-hybrid-integration-with-office-365-test-rest-api-calls/) how it works, how it needs to be setup/configured etc.

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting it and accept the answer. So that it can be useful in the community as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Yes, it's supported for with these feature set (Mail, Calendar, Contacts). Check the above [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support) itself.
2 & 3: When Microsoft Graph identifies that a REST API call is attempting to access an on-premises mailbox in a hybrid deployment, it proxies the REST request to an on-premises REST endpoint which then processes the request. This discovery makes accessing the REST API possible.
4: Here's the [detailed workflow](https://lecafedeva.wordpress.com/2019/03/15/deep-dive-how-to-configure-exchange-on-premise-server-hybrid-integration-with-office-365-test-rest-api-calls/) how it works, how it needs to be setup/configured etc